# FirebaseError: invalid stream token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

After changing a cloud function I’m getting the following error for any write operation to my database: `FirebaseError: invalid stream token`. After changing the functions back and redeploying, the error still remains. I was unable to find any reference to this error in Firebase docs. Anyone know what this is about?

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" this. For anyone else who runs into the error:

```
> rm package-lock.json
> rm -rf node-modules/
> npm install
```

Would still be nice to have a reference to this somewhere though.