# Firebase + React Native: Invalid Stream Token

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error 'invalid stream token' when using Firebase and React native.  The code I am using is pretty simple:

```
window.firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (auth) => {
  if (auth) {
    const uid = auth.uid;

    await window.firebaseApp
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(auth.uid)
      .update({
        lastSignIn: 10,
      });
  }
});
```

I have initialized Firebase, and I can see the correct UID coming back in auth.uid.

I noticed that when I run this in debugger mode and can step through the javascript in my web browser, I do not encounter this issue.  However, when it is not in debugger mode (and everything is running on my phone) this issue appears.

Versions from my package.json:

```
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.2.2",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.3.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.1",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.7.4",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.1",
"atob": "^2.1.2",
"expo": "~37.0.3",
"expo-asset": "~8.1.5",
"expo-av": "~8.1.0",
"expo-constants": "~9.0.0",
"expo-font": "~8.1.0",
"expo-web-browser": "~8.2.1",
"firebase": "7.15.5",
"react": "~16.9.0",
"react-dom": "~16.9.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
"react-native-screens": "2.2.0",
"react-native-svg": "11.0.1",
"react-native-typography": "1.4.1",
"react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
"react-native-webview": "8.1.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"react-request": ">=3.1.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

[image: Invalid stream token]

Comment: I attempted the solution here which did not help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62526185/firebaseerror-invalid-stream-token

Comment: This has been fixed in Firestore v7.1.5.4.